# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[M.Application.Models.ApplicationUserModel]' while attempting to activate M.Application.Services.EPDService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I need some guidance. This is my first learning project. I have 4 libraries.
Core:(which has all the entities, Interface)

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } 
    //other properties
    }
```

Infrastructure:(it has the context class, and the implementation of the interfaces)
Application:(it has all the entities , interface folder and services folder)

```
 public class ApplicationUserModel 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } 
    //other properties
    }
```

Web:(it again has all the entities, interfaces, services folder).

```
 public class ApplicationUserViewModel 
    {
        public string Title { get; set; } 
    //other properties
    }
```

The infrastructure is mapped with Application and Application is mapped with Web.
So the classes that are being used in controller are viewmodels of the Web(UI).

Now when I try to run it it gives the following error
Unable to resolve service for type **'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Manage2.Application.Models.ApplicationUserModel]' while attempting to activate 'Manage2.Application.Services.EmployeePersonalDetailsService'.**

To my understanding it is the error that ApplicationUser is registered and not ApplicationUserModel  in startup class as follows:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<int>>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole<int>>()
               .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MContext>()
               .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

My question is my understanding of error correct? Is this the right way to do ( I do not want to user _context in the web)? . Also how can I solve it?.

Comment: Yes, you may inject UserManager<ApplicationUserModel> in EmployeePersonalDetailsService. So you need register the service for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. It was okay to use ApplicationUserModel but what I was doing was this in Application library.

```
       private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUserModel> _userManager;
       UserManager<ApplicationUserModel> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```

This is not possible because I can only register ApplicationUser which is inheriting from IdentityUser and not ApplicationUserModel or AppilcationUserViewModel. So even in Apllication Library it should have been

```
       private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
       UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
```